# Equally defined variables doing the same, but still get TypeMismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to do a simple split program to extract peoples names from an Excel spreadsheet.

The code is simple enough but for some reason, two equally defined variables, that to my eye do the exact same thing just in different cells, dont work the same. The "managerName" variable throws a Error 13, Type Mismatch, but they are identical.

I checked like 20 times and cant spot the difference, so i basically just used the variable that worked with the cell numbers of the variable that doesnt work, and for some reason it doesnt throw a Error 13.

Can you help me spot why Vba says its a Type Mismatch, i just dont understand it and it drives me crazy.

I tried creating dozens variables that are exactly defined as is owner and ownerName but it always throws a type mismatch and i just dont understand why.

```
Dim manager, owner, ownerName, managerName As String
Dim apple, appleName As String
Dim title As Range

For k = 3 To lrow1
    Set owner = source.Cells(k, 5)
    If Not owner Is Nothing Then
        ownerName = Split(owner, "(")
        destination.Cells(k - 1, 2) = ownerName
    End If

    'Set owner = source.Cells(k, 6)
    'If Not owner Is Nothing Then
    '    ownerName = Split(owner, "(")
    '    destination.Cells(k - 1, 4) = ownerName
    'End If

    Set manager = source.Cells(k, 6)
    If Not manager Is Nothing Then
        managerName = Split(manager, "(")
        destination.Cells(k - 1, 4) = managerName
    End If
Next k
End Sub
```

As you can see, the code for finding the owner name, split the cell entry and then post it in the destination sheet is exactly the same as the one below it thats commented out, the only difference is the cells it refers to (just each a column to the right). The manager and managerName code is identical to the one above thats commented out.

For some reason VBA throws the Type Mismatch error in the line "managerName = Split(manager, "(")" with the manager code, but not for the here commented out second set of owner code in the block directly above.

I just dont get it. You can try it yourself, maybe my VBA is broken or something. Im using Excel 2010 if thats important.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: `Split` returns an array, not a `String`.

Comment: `Dim manager, owner, ownerName, managerName As String` only `managerName` is declared as `String`, `manager, owner, ownerName` are implicit `Variants`

Comment: `ownerName` is missing an index, because it's an array with the splitted names obtained from `ownerName = Split(owner, "(")`. So you need to use `OwnerName(0), OwnerName(1),OwnerName(2)` and so on. Same for `managerName `

Comment: Thank you all for the help, i am new to VBA and thought that declaring it like that would mean that all are declared as Strings. It works now and i learned something new! 

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

First of all your declarations are not identical. To be identical you must write them this way:

Dim manager **As String**, owner **As String**, ownerName **As String**, managerName As String

Dim apple **As String**, appleName As String

Dim title As Range

When type is omitted, variable is declared as variant by default.

So the block with ownerName is executed fine as there is a variant that ends up containing an array by the Split function,

but the block with managerName throws an error because it's a string and cannot contain an array.

Comment: Thank you! 

Im new to VbA and thought a declaration like this would work, since i have seen it in other code, but guess i was wrong. Do you know if there is any way to declare variables like this or do they have to be declared all single handedly like in your correction?

Thanks again!

Comment: Don't worry. It's a common mistake that many of us did when started. As far as I understand your question, this is the only way to declare variables. Please consider to mark this as answer. If you need sth else tell me so.